# Is there a fast way to convert ALL tris to quads?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

is there a fast way to convert ALL tris of a mesh into quads without leaving some behind? With fast I mean without manually editing them, because I have around 150 meshes to convert. In my case, it doesn't have to be 100% accurate.

Comment: What does Alt J give? (or Ctrl F > Tris to Quads)

Comment: You can set max shape angle and max face angle to 180 degrees on alt j tris-to-quads, but it's not guaranteed to give all quads.  For the most general version of this question, you're never going to be able to turn an odd number of triangles into all quads, there aren't the right number of vertices.

Comment: Nope sry, as Nathan said, it leaves single triangles in the mesh. Is it maybe possible by using a remesh modifier? I rarely use it, so I don't know which settings would be best, without destroying the geometry.

Comment: Remesh will change your topology, which doesn't seem to be what you want

Comment: It wouldn't matter that much, but with remesh it becomes very messy and chaotic.

Comment: In that case maybe try the Remesh > Quad in the Object Data panel?